# What is the difference between typing long x = 43 and long x = 43L in Java?

Tags: java

What would be the difference between `long x = 43` and `long x = 43L` in Java?

Do both of them initialize x to be have the long data type?

Comment: It wouldn't be much of a `long` if it stored and `int`.

Comment: The compiler handles the conversion of the integer literal. There's no difference in the resulting bytecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do both of them initialize x to be have the long data type?

Absolutely. The type of the variable is *entirely* determined by the declaration part, not the initialization.

Your first form is logically equivalent to:

```
long x = (long) 43;
```

... but there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `long`, so you don't need to put the cast there.

(In reality the compiler performs the conversion to `long` so it's a `long` constant in the bytecode, but that's an implementation detail to some extent.)

Comment: So what is the 'L' needed for in the second case if there's an implicit conversion, aka why not just write the first one?

Comment: @SidwynKoh: It's not needed in this case - it *is* needed if you're trying to represent a number greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, or if you want to call a method which is overloaded for both `int` and `long`. Basically it's the difference between "this is an `int` literal; convert it to `long` before assigning it to `x`" and "this is a `long` literal; just assign it to `x`."

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are identical. Consider:

```
long x1 = 43;
long x2 = 43L;
```

which becomes:

```
LDC 43
LSTORE 1
LDC 43
LSTORE 3
```

---

The `L` becomes necessary for longer literals:

```
long x1 = 100000000000;   // doesn't compile
long x2 = 100000000000L;  // compiles
```

`100000000000`, for instance, is out of range for int literals, so it must be explicitly made into a long literal via the terminating `L`.

Answer (score 1):

The `L` is a simple way to specify you are writing a long.

The difference is best seen through:

```
long x = 2147483648; // Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1
long x = 2147483648L;
```

Only the second will compile, since the first one, written as an `int` exceeds the range of a 32-bit signed integer.

Answer (score 0):

> Do both of them initialize x to be have the long data type?

Yes, because an `int` value can be used where a `long` is expected (called a ["widening conversion"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) in the Java language specification).  But the other way around (using a `long` for something that expects an `int`) requires an explicit cast, so you acknowledge that there's a potential loss of information if the value is beyond the range that `int` can represent.