# Is there a difference in how I initialize a variable: float f = 100; or float f = 100f?

Tags: java, floating-point

Java.

Is there a difference in a way I initialize a variable:

```
float f = 100; //implies a cast from integer to float
```

or

```
float f = 100f; //simply a float initialization
```

Can the results be different?

Here I tried to do it with a very big floats, but looks like the loss of precision is the same.

```
float f1 = (float)2000000000;
float f2 = (float)2000000050;
float f3 = 2000000000f;
float f4 = 2000000050f;
System.out.println(f1 + " " + f2 + " " + (f1==f2) + " " + f3 + " " + f4 + " "+ (f3==f4) );
```

-> 2.0E9 2.0E9 true 2.0E9 2.0E9 true

Any difference with the doubles?

Comment: There are  no doubles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring floats, why default type double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369726/declaring-floats-why-default-type-double)

Comment: There is a difference between `float f1 = 1.01161128282547f;` and `float f2 = 1.01161128282547;`, if you are interested. Both are straightforward to compile to the same bytecode operations, but the constant `(float) 1.01161128282547` that `f2` receives is different from `1.01161128282547f` that `f1` receives.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I assume that's because `float f2 = 1.01161128282547` goes through an extra step; `valueOf` starts with a conceptual infinite-precision float, but your expression for `f1` rounds the infinite-precision to a `float`, and `f2` rounds the infinite-precision to a `double` first and then a `float`.

Comment: @ajb Exactly. The decimal number 1.01161128282547 is one of these numbers so close to the exact middle between two floats that if you first round it to `double`, it changes the result as opposed to directly rounding it to `float`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442286/what-is-the-difference-between-typing-long-x-43-and-long-x-43l-in-java

Comment: @PascalCuoq: My preferred number of that type is `((1L<<53)+(1L<<29)+1)`, since one can very easily see the effect of rounding to `double` and then `float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the results will be the same.  The JLS rules for interpreting a floating-point literal refer to the `valueOf(String s)` method of `Float` and `Double` types; the rules for a type conversion from integer to float types are given by JLS 5.1.2.  Both refer to "IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode".  So I think it's safe to assume the results are the same.